# En el jdialog no se ve ningún elemento

Tags: java, progressbar, diálogo

He creado una modal de espera que lanzo como un Thread, pero cuando lo ejecuto se muestra el jdialog sin la progressBar:

```
public class ModalEspera_v2 extends Thread{

private JFrame frame;
private JFrame frmProcesarFacturasSolred;
private JDialog dialog;

public ModalEspera_v2() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public ModalEspera_v2(JFrame frmProcesarFacturasSolred) {
    super();
    this.frmProcesarFacturasSolred = frmProcesarFacturasSolred;
    dialog = new JDialog(frmProcesarFacturasSolred, "", ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    //frame = new JFrame();
    dialog.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    //dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    dialog.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Procesando...");
    lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(12, 60, 214, 30);
    dialog.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

    JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
    progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressBar.setBounds(44, 118, 336, 43);
    dialog.getContentPane().add(progressBar);
    dialog.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    initialize();
}

public void destroy()
{
    dialog.setVisible(false);
    dialog.dispose();
}
```

}

Comment: Puedes agregar el código con la llamada a esta clase? (Cómo se crea principalmente) Necesitamos saber de qué manera lo llamas para ver la ejecución que sigue el programa. Y explica un poco los constructores.

Comment: He visto el problema. Si ejecuto a continuación de esta llamada otro hilo, por ejemplo Thread.sleep(5000), no se ve nada, si elimino la creación de otros hilos a continuación de esta ModalEspera se muestra. He encontrado el problema pero sigo sin saber la solución, ya que los hilos que creo después son necesarios para acelerar la ejecución del programa.

Comment: Es mejor saber que es lo que quieres lograr con lo que intentas hacer. Porque los hilos solo te van ayudar a desacoplar la parte grafica de los procesos en segundo plano pero para que funcionen bien seria mejor empezar conociendo la idea general.

Comment: Por favor, añade el código del invocador, es decir de las llamadas, no solo el de esta clase. Sino, no podremos ayudarte a encontrar y solucionar el problema. Puedes haber identificado las condiciones en las que se produce, pero no sabes realmente la causa. ¿No será que llamas al método `run` de `Thread` en vez de a `start`? Todo eso quedaría resuelto con ver más código.

Comment: Ya lo he solucionado. Como decía el problema era de los hilos. Cambié el orden de ejecución de forma que se creen primero los hilos de mi proceso en background y luego creo la ventana de espera. Gracias a todos.